# To ground capacitance of a power line modelling

Tags: mains

Is it correct to model to ground capacitance of an overhead power line as ideal current source when using matrix methods for load flow calculation?

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen it modeled as a current source, if you know the distances and sizes of your cables and the distance to ground it is possible to calculate the capacitance itself and consider it an impedance in your power flow.

$$
Cn = \frac{2\pi\epsilon}{ln\frac{D}{r}}\frac Fm
$$

Is the most basic formula, there are more advanced ones, but this one is a decent approximation.

So I would just calculate, get the impedance depending on your frequency and just add it to your matrix. This will just affect the elements on the main diagonal.

source for the formula:

https://circuitglobe.com/capacitance-of-transmission-line.html

Comment: If you take a look at equivalent schemes of a power line, to-ground capacitances are located in to-ground admittances. The reactive power they generate is in stationary state only voltage-dependent. Taking into consideration the fact that voltages vary around nominal voltage, you can make an approximation and model the capacitances as current sources using nominal voltage.

Comment: why even do the power flow if you are going to assume nominal voltage as the  voltage on the node.

Comment: The mistake that comes with this approximation is really negligible

Comment: you are not wrong, in p.u most voltages would be between 0.99 and 1.01,around a 1% deviation at worst. However, this is exactly the reason you do the power flow proper to confirm that this hold true.

Comment: To support @Juan 's argument, the capacitance can be easily modeled in PI-circuit in most power flow software. For example, see [the line model in `pandapower`](https://pandapower.readthedocs.io/en/develop/elements/line.html#electric-model).